# Why are there two Eclipse CDT tags ([cdt] and [eclipse-cdt])?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is a tag for [cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdt) and one for [eclipse-cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-cdt). As far as I can tell they are both for the Eclipse CDT project, neither for a specific aspect of that project, they were both created around the same time, both are reasonably active and CDT questions are often tagged with both (as well as [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) and others).

Maybe one is for developing *for* CDT and one is for developing *with* CDT?
If there is no difference then maybe one should be removed? (Personally I'd vote to get rid of [cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdt))

**EDIT:** Matt suggested a synonym and I now note that [eclipse-cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-cdt) has a suggested synonym of [cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdt). Sadly I do not yet have quite enough rep to vote on the suggestion :'(

Comment: Assuming they both unambiguously refer to the same technology a tag synonym might be a better option.

Comment: @Matt Good idea... ah, I dont have enough rep, grr

Comment: Someone else might see this that can suggest it assuming it is good idea (I dont know enough to help). I would also opt for `cdt` being a synonym of the longer /more versbose `eclipse-cdt`

Comment: Synonym has been suggested, time to vote for it now http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse-cdt/synonyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is - at this time and probably ever - no good reason to have both  `eclipse-cdt` and `cdt` should definitely be synonyms of the same tags. The info pages makes no distinction between these two.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: The syn. is now approved.